# Bishop - Pattern Recognition & Machine Learning, Exercise 1.2

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, machine-learning

I'm working on exercise 1.2 (Curve Fitting Problem) of Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning book.

You should write the linear equations, satisfied by the coefficients, that minimize the regularized sum-of-squares error function $\tilde E(w) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 1}^N (y(x_n, w) - t_n)^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|w\|^2$ with $y(x, w) = \sum_{j = 0}^M w_jx^j$ and $\|w\|^2 = w^Tw$ for given data $(x_n, t_n)$.

Similar to exercise 1.1, I started with the partial derivative for the weight $w_i$ with $A_{ij} = \sum_{n = 1}^N (x_n)^{i + j}$ and $T_i = \sum_{n = 1}^N (x_n)^it_n$ from the first exercise:
$$
\frac{\partial \tilde E}{\partial w_i}(0.5 \sum_{n = 1}^N (y(x_n, w) - t_n)^2 + \lambda / 2 \|w\|^2) \\
= \frac{\partial \tilde E}{\partial w_i}(0.5 \sum_{n = 1}^N (y(x_n, w) - t_n)^2) + \frac{\partial \tilde E}{\partial w_i}( \lambda / 2 \|w\|^2) \\
= \sum_{j = 0}^M A_{ij}w_j - T_i + \lambda / 2 \frac{\partial \tilde E}{\partial w_i}(\|w\|^2) \\
= \sum_{j = 0}^M A_{ij}w_j - T_i + \lambda / 2 \cdot 2w_i = \sum_{j = 0}^M A_{ij}w_j - T_i + \lambda w_i
$$

Now I could set this derivative to zero and get
$$
\sum_{j = 0}^M (A_{ij}w_j) + \lambda w_i = T_i
$$

And at this point I've no idea, how to get this equation in a form of a linear system for using for example the gauss algorithm.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are there. Maybe slightly rewriting your last equation helps:

$$
A_{i1} w_1 + A_{i2} w_2 + ... + (A_{ii} + \lambda) w_i + ... + A_{iM} w_M = T_i
$$

and you have $M$ of these equations.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is it too. Probably it's a way smarter to write it as matrices: $(A + \lambda I)w = T$
For the gaussian algorithm it is sufficient to calculate the sum mentioned above and use it as the left side in the algorithm, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, matrix notation is less cluttered for sure. I didn't double-check your derivation but I believe that $A$ is positive definite hence you can solve the problem by simple matrix inversion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the math goes, I think there is a slight mistake with regards to the derivative of the penalty term.  Substituting the index representation of the penalty term before taking the derivative helps to illustrate.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \tilde E}{\partial w_i} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}\left( \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^N \left[ y(x_n, \mathbf{w}) - t_n \right]^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2} \|w\|^2 \right) \\
 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial w_i} \left( \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^N \left[ y(x_n, \mathbf{w}) - t_n \right]^2 \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial w_i} \left( \frac{\lambda}{2} \|w\|^2 \right) \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^M A_{ij}w_j - T_i + \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_{j=0}^M \frac{\partial w_j^2}{\partial w_i} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^M A_{ij}w_j - T_i + \lambda \sum_{j=0}^M w_j \delta_{ij} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^M \left( A_{ij} + \lambda \delta_{ij} \right) w_j - T_i
\end{align}
$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) and corresponds to the identity matrix.

Comment: It seems to be the same thing as in the question.